# Import error with local import produce "attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Tags: python

I would like make the following, but i don't understand how solve the `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` error:

```
(venv3.7) ➜  testing ✗ python myimporttest/folder1/a.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myimporttest/folder1/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .folder2 import s
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
(venv3.7) ➜  testing ✗ tree myimporttest 
myimporttest
└── folder1
    ├── a.py
    ├── folder2
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── s.py
    └── __init__.py

2 directories, 4 files
```

I have `__init__.py` files but it is like not enough ... I can see answer about this error **but no one with this folder structure and import**.

Comment: What does `os.getcwd()` return?

Comment: you are not in the directory where it can find folder 2. Try `import sys` then `sys.path.append(folder1_path)`

Comment: @0buz  `os.getcwd()` return the path of `myimpoerttest` folder

Comment: @Obuz: the folder containing `myimporttest`. @Toby: nothing change. Making "from .xx" is relative from execution folder, not from current file importing ?

Comment: importing without `.` is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `folder2` is not same as the `.folder2`.

just change you code to

```
from folder2 import s
```

Comment: how are those two not same?